# Install sdkman in docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, sdk, docker-compose

Getting error while installing `SDKMAN!` in `Ubuntu 16.04` docker image.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl
RUN curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
RUN chmod a+x "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Comment: What's the error?  You didn't say what the error was, so we can't help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure you have curl, wget, unzip & zip. With them I am able to install Sdkman successfully. Following is my Docker content

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl wget unzip zip

RUN curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Comment: why wget if it is not used?

Answer (score 5):

This Dockerfile seems to work with versions current as of February 2023:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl zip unzip
RUN curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

# this SHELL command is needed to allow using source
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]    

# seems you need to put 'sdk install...'' lines in same RUN command as 'source...'.
RUN source "/root/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"   \
                && sdk install java 19.0.2-tem  \
                && sdk install sbt 1.8.2        \
                && sdk install scala 2.13.10
```

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

Install `unzip` & `zip`, which means change

```
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl
```

to

```
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl unzip zip
```

or better

```
RUN apt-get -qq -y install \
    curl \
    unzip \
    zip
```

---

### Explanation

When you try to build the Dockerfile, you will get

```
    .....

    Step 5/6 : RUN curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
    ---> Running in 1ce678a59561

    --- SDKMAN LOGO ---

    Now attempting installation...

    Looking for a previous installation of SDKMAN...
    Looking for unzip...
    Not found.
    ======================================================================================================
    Please install unzip on your system using your favourite package manager.

    Restart after installing unzip.
    ======================================================================================================

    Removing intermediate container 1ce678a59561
    ---> 22211eafd50c
    Step 6/6 : RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
    ---> Running in 1c5cb7d79ef0
    /bin/sh: /root/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh: No such file or directory
    The command '/bin/sh -c source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What you need to do is written just there. This part:

```
    ======================================================================================================
    Please install unzip on your system using your favourite package manager.

    Restart after installing unzip.
    ======================================================================================================
```

When you install unzip, you get the same error with zip. After installing it, everything works fine.

So, read your logs/command output. :-)

---

*P.S. It would be better if  `curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash` exited with non-zero code. This way it fails on the next command. But that is not a thing you can fix ;) *

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) install failed. 
When I ran your code above it complained about missing the `unzip` and `zip` packages.

After satisfying the dependencies, you'll also need to mark the init script as executable with:

```
chmod a+x "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

So your Dockerfile should look something like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -q -y install curl zip unzip
RUN curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
RUN chmod a+x "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

P.S: Beaten to the punch!

Comment: I'm getting sdk command not found in the middle of the build, is there something missing if I need to install a library from the sdkman after those steps in your answer?

Comment: @PabloPazos I ran into the same problem, had to use add my commands (ie using && ) after the "RUN source $HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

Answer (score 2):

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -qq -y install \
    curl \
    unzip \
    zip
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl
RUN curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
RUN chmod a+x "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Comment: `FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -qq -y install \
    curl \
    unzip \
    zip
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl
RUN curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
RUN chmod a+x "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" `

Answer (score 0):

```
docker pull kubile/ubuntu-sdkman:23.04
```

You can try this image.